# get a listing of unique count of occurrences for a set of variables in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to get a listing of unique count of occurrences for a set of variables in a data.table. The following code works. 
I was just wondering if it is possible to generalise this with a function. It may then have more general applicability for data of moderate size.

```
packageVersion('data.table')
[1] ‘1.9.7’
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(x1=c("b","c", "a", "b", "a", "b",'b'), x2=as.character(c(1:6,1)),m1=c(seq(10,60,by=10),10),m2=1:7)
DT
> DT
   x1 x2 m1 m2
1:  b  1 10  1
2:  c  2 20  2
3:  a  3 30  3
4:  b  4 40  4
5:  a  5 50  5
6:  b  6 60  6
7:  b  1 10  7

###get unique counts of each occurrence of first variable x1
setkey(DT,x1)
u1<-DT[,.(uN1=uniqueN(.SD)),by=x1]
U1<-u1[DT]
U1
> U1
   x1 uN1 x2 m1 m2
1:  a   2  3 30  3
2:  a   2  5 50  5
3:  b   4  1 10  1
4:  b   4  4 40  4
5:  b   4  6 60  6
6:  b   4  1 10  7
7:  c   1  2 20  2

###unique counts of (x1,x2)
setkey(U1,x1,x2)
u2<-U1[,.(uN2=uniqueN(.SD)),by=.(x1,x2)]
U2<-u2[U1]
U2
> U2
   x1 x2 uN2 uN1 m1 m2
1:  a  3   1   2 30  3
2:  a  5   1   2 50  5
3:  b  1   2   4 10  1
4:  b  1   2   4 10  7
5:  b  4   1   4 40  4
6:  b  6   1   4 60  6
7:  c  2   1   1 20  2

###unique counts of (x1,x2,m1)
setkey(U2,x1,x2,m1)
u3<-U2[,.(uN3=uniqueN(.SD)),by=.(x1,x2,m1)]
U3<-u3[U2]
# desired order
setcolorder(U3,c('x1','uN1','x2','uN2','m1','uN3','m2'))
U3
> U3
   x1 uN1 x2 uN2 m1 uN3 m2
1:  a   2  3   1 30   1  3
2:  a   2  5   1 50   1  5
3:  b   4  1   2 10   2  1
4:  b   4  1   2 10   2  7
5:  b   4  4   1 40   1  4
6:  b   4  6   1 60   1  6
7:  c   1  2   1 20   1  2
```

The proposed function can be something like:

```
UniqueCombN(DT, listX)
```

where `listX` is a list of the variables of interest in the data table.

Comment: Just using `DT[, uN1:=uniqueN(.SD), x1][, uN2:=uniqueN(.SD), .(x1,x2)][, uN3:=uniqueN(.SD), .(x1,x2,m1)]` would give you the same result.

Comment: @Jaap Your suggestion appears to be just what I was looking for. Apart from the column ordering. But that's something that can be fixed easily.

Comment: @Jaap lets keep trying to answer the question to not have them listed in the unanswered list, if you are not going to you can suggest that to Vivek to selfanswer with your code.

Comment: @jangorecki posted my comment as an answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The several joins you used are not needed. You can achieve the same result by updating your `data.table` by reference with:

```
DT[, uN1:=uniqueN(.SD), x1
   ][, uN2:=uniqueN(.SD), .(x1,x2)
     ][, uN3:=uniqueN(.SD), .(x1,x2,m1)]
```

gives:

```
> DT
   x1 x2 m1 m2 uN1 uN2 uN3
1:  b  1 10  1   4   2   2
2:  c  2 20  2   1   1   1
3:  a  3 30  3   2   1   1
4:  b  4 40  4   4   1   1
5:  a  5 50  5   2   1   1
6:  b  6 60  6   4   1   1
7:  b  1 10  7   4   2   2
```

If you want to set the order, you can use for example:

```
setorder(DT, x1, x2)
```

which gives:

```
> DT
   x1 x2 m1 m2 uN1 uN2 uN3
1:  a  3 30  3   2   1   1
2:  a  5 50  5   2   1   1
3:  b  1 10  1   4   2   2
4:  b  1 10  7   4   2   2
5:  b  4 40  4   4   1   1
6:  b  6 60  6   4   1   1
7:  c  2 20  2   1   1   1
```

Arranging the columns in a different order can be done like you did in your question:

```
setcolorder(DT, c('x1','uN1','x2','uN2','m1','uN3','m2'))
```